# online phone, call forwarding, and tracking when an income call is achieved? | Website Project

Tags: php, mysql, phone-number

I want to do the following things:

1. Have a website with bunch of phone numbers which are connected to the costumers number
2. whenever a phone call is achieved toward that number, it will forward the call to the costumer's number and record the time of the call in a mysql table
3. next, be able to store the conversation for the costumer to reference.

Now I can make the website, MySQL Table, and all of that, but I have no clue about how to get bunch of numbers which will just forward to a different number which will be owned by the costumer.

So here is an example of a situation

Costumer number - 001-001-0011
number on website - 002-002-0022

when the person will call 002-002-0022 it should forward the call to 001-001-0011 and mark in mysql that there had been a phone call at that time or launch a php script, next, it will store the phone call online, for example, upload it on to my website.

is there some kind of service online or something I could use to achieve this?

its kind of hard to explain the whole thing, so i tried to do my best.

Is this even possible? would I need special equipment maybe to record calls or to acquire the numbers?

Answer (score 1):

There are several services that provide that kind of functionality:

- https://www.callfire.com/api-documentation
- http://www.twilio.com/platform/usage
- ifbyphone.com (cannot paste more than two links)
- tollfreeforwarding.com (cannot paste more than two links)

Disclaimer: I am currently looking for such a service myself and have not tried any of the above yet.